# AWS lambda clone git repository and make zip not able to upload in s3

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to try to clone my git repository which is in a private github . I can  see that after adding webhooks and set up cloud formation as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/git-to-s3-using-webhooks/).

It is sending request to my lambda. I am able to clone the repository be below ways but not able to create zip of the repository and upload it to s3 as in Lambda I can not find where is it storing the repository to make it zip and upload it from that path.

```
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
import logging
import base64
import os
import shutil
from zipfile import ZipFile
from cStringIO import StringIO

# Set to False to allow self-signed/invalid ssl certificates
verify = False

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

   path        =   "/gitpull" 
   clone       =   "git clone https://username:pwd@site.com/scm/awsdemos/testrepo.git" 

# os.system("sshpass -p your_password ssh user_name@your_localhost")
  os.chdir(path) 

  os.system(clone) # Cloning
#   folder = "/gitpull"
#   logger.info(os.listdir(folder))

#   shutil.make_archive('Gitpull', 'zip', '/tmp')
   s3_archive_file = "Gitpull.zip" 

    # Create zip from /tmp dir without any common prefixes
   shutil.make_archive('Gitpull', 'zip', os.getcwd())
   logger.info("Uploading zip to S3://%s/%s" % ('gitpulls3', s3_archive_file))
   s3_client.upload_file(os.getcwd(), 'gitpulls3', s3_archive_file)
   logger.info('Upload Complete')
```

is there any good way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Change s3_client.upload_file to below code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(os.getcwd() + "/" + s3_archive_file_name, 'mybucket', s3_archive_file_name)
```

Check below code I have tried on Lambda function:

```
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
import logging
import base64
import os
import shutil
from zipfile import ZipFile

# Set to False to allow self-signed/invalid ssl certificates
verify = False

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.info("hello")
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

   path        =   "/tmp" 
   clone       =   "git clone https://github.com/sirajpathan/test.git" 

# os.system("sshpass -p your_password ssh user_name@your_localhost")
   logger.info(os.getcwd())
   os.chdir(path) 

   os.system(clone) # Cloning
   #os.chdir(os.getcwd())
   folder = os.getcwd() + "/tmp"
   logger.info(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
   logger.info(os.listdir("/tmp"))

   #shutil.make_archive('Gitpull', 'zip', '/tmp')
   s3_archive_file = 'test.zip'

    # Create zip from /tmp dir without any common prefixes
   shutil.make_archive('test', 'zip', os.getcwd())
   logger.info(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
   logger.info("Uploading zip to S3://%s/%s" % ('testsiraj1', s3_archive_file))
   #used s3 meta client below
   s3.meta.client.upload_file(os.getcwd() + "/" + s3_archive_file, 'testsiraj1', s3_archive_file)
   ##s3_client.upload_file(os.getcwd(), 'bucketname', s3_archive_file)
   logger.info('Upload Complete')
```

Comment: I got Read-only file system: '/var/task/gitpull'

Comment: only /tmp seems to be writable in lambda

Comment: @harikrishnamurthy try updated code now. its working in lambda too

Comment: empty zip file uploaded

Comment: Rename test folder to your repo name or you can try my public repo for testing

Comment: @sirajpathan I see zip file in my s3 with no files inside  even after changing the reponame or using your public repo

Comment: it can only work for public repo. how can you make it to work for private repo using ssh connection?